# Generate HTML with css from React elements

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, react-dom-server

i'm trying to generate HTML with css from react elements using the following code.

```
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<ReactComponent/>);
```

I'm using Material UI components in the react elements. Css is not applied in the generated HTML.

How to generate a HTML with css ?